# Framework7 navbar overlap on iOS

Tags: html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 version 8.2.0 and the navbars of my two pages overlap on iOS only (not on Android) when I emulate these devices in Firefox, Chrome or Edge:

Here is what I am getting on iOS emulation (Edge):

[image: iOS emulation on Edge]

And here is what I am getting on Android emulation (Edge):

[image: Android emulation on Edge]
Here is my simplified HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framework7@8.2.0/framework7-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framework7-icons@5.0.5/css/framework7-icons.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="view view-main">
        <div data-name="info" class="page">
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
            <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
              <div class="left">
                <a href="/" class="link">
                  <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                  back
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="title">test 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="page-content tab" id="tab-about">
            About
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-name="home" class="page">
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
            <div class="navbar-inner">
              <div class="title">
                test
              </div>
              <div class="right margin-right-half">
                <a href="/info/" class="margin-right-half"><i class="icon f7-icons">info_circle_fill</i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framework7@8.2.0/framework7-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```js
let app = new Framework7({el: '#app', name: 'testing', panel: {swipe: true}, routes: [{path: '/', pageName: 'home'}, {path: '/info/', pageName: 'info'}]});
let mainView = app.views.create('.view-main');
```

I created this example from the official documentation, putting together a simple app and an info page.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omichel/0vbaL1ge/1/) to run this code with the iOS theme. Changing the `theme` on the first line of the of the JavaScript from `ios` to `md` fixes the problem. However, I would like my app run well on iOS too.

One possible workaround is adding this line to my JavaScrip code:

```js
app.views.main.router.navigate('/', {animate:false});
```

Another workaround is to disable dynamic navbar on iOS:

```js
let mainView = app.views.create('.view-main', {iosDynamicNavbar: false});
```

However, it shouldn't be necessary to do this, as it should work nicely out-of-the-box.

I am doing anything wrong or is that a bug?